# What is the difference between wxSocketServer and wxTcpServer?

Tags: windows, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

I am using wxWidgets 3.0.2 with mingw-w64 (g++) and would like to write a server that listens on a TCP port and can maintain multiple connections from clients simultaneously.

There is documentation along with one official code sample for [wxSocketServer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_socket_server.html).  There is also a class called [wxTCPServer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_t_c_p_server.html) which has bare-bones documentation.

However I have been unable to find (by googling) any code samples or explanation relating to wxTCPServer. What is the difference between the two and which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wxTCPServer` is a TCP-based implementation of the wxWidgets IPC protocol (the other implementation, available only under MSW, uses DDE). Normally you should not use it directly but use `wxServer` instead. Of course, if you need a generic socket server, you should use `wxSocketServer` itself and not either of these classes.

Better yet, use a dedicated socket/network library such as (Boost) [ASIO](http://think-async.com/) or [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/). wxWidgets TCP support is very basic and should be only used for relatively simple things, i.e. when neither performance nor scalability matter.

Comment: so SocketServer is the generic TCP/IP server, and TCPServer is something else. Clear as mud :) Thanks for the other suggestions too.

Comment: `wxTCPServer` is the TCP version of `wxServer` so it kind of makes sense but only if you squint a lot. In any case, the only thing you need to know about `wxTCPServer` is that you shouldn't use it, so its name is the last thing to worry about...